# centering scaled element beyond window width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div `#content-wrapper`, nested inside is one div `#canvas-blur` and a `main` element. All elements should be the same width and height of the viewport/window, but #canvas-blur has the CSS `transform: scale(1.1);` making it larger. Within the `#canvas-blur`div there is a canvas element that is set to the size of the viewport/window, on this canvas I have created a painting tool that tracks the mouse position. The problem is that `#canvas-blur` is scaled from the left top corner (see Appendix 1) which effects the mouse positions on the canvas (see pictures). I need `#canvas-blur` to scale from the center like (see Appendix 2). This means that `main` and `#canvas-blur` will have the same center points and will scroll together like illustrated in Appendix 3. Any pointer in the right direction would be useful.

edit: added [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvL8jv4j/2/)

[image]

```css
#content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#canvas-blur {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <main>

  </main>
  <div id="canvas-blur">
    <canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

MOUSE
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like transform-origin might be what  you need.

Try adding this to #canvas-blur

```
transform-origin: center;
```

You could also try adding this to main to center the content both horizontally and vertically since you are using flex:

```
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle so I can see?

Comment: have you tried the flex properties on the id=content-wrapper?